# Microsoft CRM 2011 - Created new user unable to access the system

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have created two accounts from the Active Directory, and those accounts are unable to access the system, but the account that was used to create the Organization for the first time doesn't seem to have that problem.

The error on the website with DevError set to On :

> An error has occurred.
>
> Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Crm.MainApplication.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)

Stack trace using CRMDiagTool 2011 :

```
 Stack Trace Info: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppNavBar..ctor()
at ASP.sunway_main_aspx.__BuildControlTree(sunway_main_aspx __ctrl)
at ASP.sunway_main_aspx.FrameworkInitialize()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

There are three accounts, one created on installation that can access the CRM website no problem, but the two accounts created are unable to access the CRM website.

How do I fix this ? is there a roll up for this issue ?

Thanks,

***Note** : IIS currently using NetworkService as identity, the account that can access the website is the current deployment administrator.

Comment: What is `ASP.sunway_main_aspx.FrameworkInitialize()`? That is not part of Dynamics CRM. What security roles have you assigned the new users? Can all three access from the same workstation? Got to eliminate workstation authentication errors.

Comment: I got that from using the Diagnostic Tool. All three users have the same security roles, currently I have given them all System Administrator. And how do you mean by accessing the same workstation ? if by remote accessing the server then yes they can. Thanks.

Comment: So is that stack trace from the CRMDiagTool execution stack or is that the CRM server stack trace being read by the CRMDiagTool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The Client Access License (CAL) for those accounts were set to Administrative, it seems that I don't have the required license for 3 Administrative CALs, after changing the Client Access License (CAL) Access Mode to "Read-Write" everything was working fine.